# Is there a way to extract ID from autocomplete in Rails 3.2 app?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

The autocomplete implemented in `bom` model works fine. Here is autocomplete related code in `bom` model:

```
belongs_to :part, :class_name => BillOfBaseMaterialx.part_class.to_s

def part_name_autocomplete
  self.part.try(:name)
end

def part_name_autocomplete=(name)
  self.part = BillOfBaseMaterialx.part_class.find_by_name(name) if name.present?
end
```

After a user selects a `part name` generated by `autocomplete`, we would like to save `part id` to @part_id in controller and pass the @part_id to views for further processing. However other than the `part name` in `params[:bom][:part_name_autocomplete]`, we did not find object `@part` or anything related to `part id`. We can still retrieve `part` object with its name, however we would prefer to have `part id` instead. Is there a way to retrieve `part id` after autocomplete?

Comment: This is fuzzy language you're using... Do you mean you are trying to get the ID of a retrieved record??

Comment: Yes, ID of the retrieved record.

Comment: Part.where(:name, the_name_you_have).first.id would be one solution, if you have just a name without an object

Comment: This is what we are doing now - using the part name to retrieve the part object. However we would like to use id instead.

Comment: Ok... how are you implementing autocomplete? You probably need to override or alter the server function to provide the id of the fetched part as well, preferably in some json object (I guess) and use javascript to add it to a hidden field.

Comment: Autocomplete has been implemented and working. We just want to find a way to use id instead of part name to search for the part.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-app/blob/master/app/views/welcome/_form.html.erb